# Como fazer while em PDO e manipulação de dados?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer um while com PDO e pegar cada dado, manipula-los e jogar dentro de um array.
Como posso fazer isso?

Meu php:

```
while ($linhaMsg=$pegaMsgsLogra->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    @$idAviso = $linhaMsg['idAvisoLogradouro'];
    @$idUsuario = $linhaMsg['idUsuario'];
    @$msg = $linhaMsg['msg'];
    @$foto = utf8_encode($linhaMsg['foto']);
    @$hora = $linhaMsg['hora'];

    $horaP = explode(':', $hora);
    $hora = $horaP[0].':'.$horaP[1];

    $return = array(
            'nome' => $nome,
            'msg' => $msg,
            'foto' => $foto,
            'hora' => $hora
        );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta acrescentar um `[]` no `$return`:

```
$return = array(); // Nem precisa desta linha, mas no mínimo fica mais fácil entender.

while ($linhaMsg=$pegaMsgsLogra->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    @$idAviso = $linhaMsg['idAvisoLogradouro'];
    @$idUsuario = $linhaMsg['idUsuario'];
    @$msg = $linhaMsg['msg'];
    @$foto = utf8_encode($linhaMsg['foto']);
    @$hora = $linhaMsg['hora'];

    $horaP = explode(':', $hora);
    $hora = $horaP[0].':'.$horaP[1];

    $return[] = array(
        'nome' => $nome,
        'msg' => $msg,
        'foto' => $foto,
        'hora' => $hora
    );

}
```

Desta forma, `$return` vai ser um *array* com outros *arrays* dentro.

O primeiro nome vai estar em `$return[0]['nome']`, o segundo em `$return[1]['nome']`, e assim por diante.